# Git push to master repo then send the dist folder to a specific path(/www/site/v0.0.1)?

Tags: linux, git, bash

So the goal is to push my project to a core repo, where all my development files live, for backup purposes.

Then I want to send the `dist` folder to a directory like `www/site.com/v0.0.1`, for demonstration purposes, no development files are needed, it would just cause bloat because I have multiple directories.

---

So what I have right now is a `.gitignore` that ignores pretty much everything but the `dist`.

I ran `git rm -r --cache` and now I am only pushing the `dist`, but now the pitfall is I cant back up my core repo, in case my local environment is destroyed, then all I have is all this compiled code, and I am not reverse engineering that.

```
#!/bin/sh
currentVersion=git describe --abbrev=0
mkdir /var/www/example.com/public_html/projects/$currentVersion
git --work-tree=/var/www/example.com/public_html/projects/$currentVersion --git-dir=/var/repo/cool.git checkout -f
```

---

I can think of two situations

1. Two remote repos (core.git, demos.git), `git add remote <ssh-repo/core.git & demos.git>`, the pitfall is with `.gitignore` how am I supposed to specify which repo uses the ignores? Also two repos kind of sucks.
2. Inside the bash script write something that enables me to ignore files, then add another worktree, or possibly just use a linux command to just take the dist and put it into my desired version for this `post-receive` event?

A third could possibly use branches, I am still a git novice and am not sure what I can do.

**EDIT:** So obviously two repos is stupid if I am just pushing the dist folder, so I think in the bash script I need to somehow take just the dist folder and use a command to copy it into my desired path.

Answer (score 0):

If the **dist** dir only contains generated artifacts and can be re-created from the rest of the **core** files I'd suggest 2 repos:

- **dist** for the generated artifacts
- **core** for the rest plus a symlink to the **dist** repo (added to git or not, each has advantages and disadvantages, up to you)

Something along this line (they don't have to be side by side, whatever's convenient for you):

```
$~/git> ls -la *
core:
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 3 user at  4096 Apr 22 22:22 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user at  4096 Apr 22 22:22 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 22811 Apr 22 22:22 blah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user at     7 Apr 22 22:22 dist -> ../dist
drwxrwxr-x 8 user at  4096 Apr 22 22:23 .git

dist:
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 user at 4096 Apr 22 22:23 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user at 4096 Apr 22 22:22 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at   84 Apr 22 22:24 blah_dist
drwxrwxr-x 8 user at 4096 Apr 22 22:24 .git
```

No need for .gitignore files.
Pushes from the **core** dir go to the source code backup repo, pushes from the **dist** dir (even from under the symlink inside **core**) go to the deployment repo(s). Git is smart enough to to not mix up the 2 repos:

```
$~/git/core> git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$~/git/core> cd dist/
$~/git/core/dist> git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   blah_dist

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$~/git/core/dist>
```

Even if you have some files that should be shared by both repos you can consider them 'generated': have them in the **core** repo and 'generate' them by plain copy into the **dist** symlink/repo as needed.

You can even automate the generation/refresh of the **dist** artifacts using a [git push hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in the **core** repo.